# What is wrong with RETURNING in my postgresql Script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I am developing an application and the database will be PostgreSQL. So now I am creating an Professional WebService which will have the CRUD operations.

The INSERT of my professional needs to run as follows:

```sql
WITH pessoa_fisica_id AS
        (INSERT INTO pessoa_fisica (
            nome,
            sobrenome,
            data_nascimento,
            cpf,
            sexo,
            email,
            logadouro,
            numero,
            complemento,
            bairro,
            cep,
            fk_municipio,
            role,
            telefone) 
            VALUES (
                'Marcia',
                'Borges',
                '09/09/1978',
                '36925874111',
                'Feminio',
                'marcia.amelia@hotmail.com',
                'Rua das macieiras',
                 25,
                '104',
                'Botafogo',
                '28640000',
                3583,
                'Profissional',
                '{
                    "tipo": "Celular",
                    "preferencial": true,
                    "ddd": 22,
                    "numero": 998929122,
                    "possuiWhatsapp": true
                 }'RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO profissional ( tipo, numero_registro_conselho,especialidade,fk_dados_pessoais) 
VALUES ('Enfermeiro','87654321','N/a', pessoa_fisica_id);
```

The problem is founded in RETURNING as the PostegreSQL message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
LINE 37:                  }' RETURNING id into pessoa_fisica_id)
                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1006
```

What is wrong with my insert statement?

Comment: You may want to scrub your data before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

First issue was a missing ) and second issue is a missing SELECT statement:

```
WITH pessoa_fisica_id AS (
    INSERT INTO pessoa_fisica ( nome, sobrenome, data_nascimento, cpf, sexo, email, logadouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, fk_municipio, ROLE, telefone )
    VALUES
        ( 'Marcia', 'Borges', '1978-09-09', '36925874111', 'Feminio', 'marcia.amelia@hotmail.com', 'Rua das macieiras', 25, '104', 'Botafogo', '28640000', 3583, 'Profissional', '{
            "tipo": "Celular",
            "preferencial": true,
            "ddd": 22,
            "numero": 998929122,
            "possuiWhatsapp": true
        }') RETURNING ID
)   
INSERT INTO profissional ( tipo, numero_registro_conselho, especialidade, fk_dados_pessoais )
SELECT
    'Enfermeiro', 
    '87654321', 
    'N/a', 
    id
FROM    pessoa_fisica_id;
```

And another issue is the data_nascimento. Never ever store a date in something else than a DATE. I'm also not sure what you want to store in the field especialidade, a value N/a sounds like a NULL and not like N/a when there is no information.

Abraço

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the answer, but here in my PgAdmin I get the same error with your code.. My version is the 9.2.24. I don´t know if it is  a problem....

Comment: @ChelloFera: I put the ) at the wrong place... Sorry! It should now work

Comment: Goood Zero Six... Standard...Thank you a lot for the help....